# How to get the week Starting and Ending date using Week number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I want get week starting date and week ending date using week number

**For example**

input

My week number = 32

**output**

```
WeekStartingDate     WeekEndingDate
------------------------------------
06-08-2017           12-08-2017
```

**Note**

Without Date. only by using week number. Is it possible?

**Update**

[image: Date Output]

Comment: Please refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cf233caf-4ccd-4bca-add2-b5eb467f2dd4/convert-week-number-to-date-of-1st-day-of-that-week?forum=transactsql. There you can find how to get the date given the week number. That doesn't completely answer your question, but would be possible to build up a solution based on the approach suggested in this post.

Comment: The result is not the same because the `@@DATEFIRST` , try `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` and you will understand what I mean,When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw) the return value depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried like this ....

```
 DECLARE @WK INT  SET @WK = 32
    DECLARE @YR INT  SET @YR = 2017

    SELECT DATEADD (WEEK, @WK, DATEADD (YEAR, @YR-1900, 0)) - 4 -
             DATEPART(DW, DATEADD (WEEK, @WK, DATEADD (YEAR, @YR-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1 AS [WEEK_STARTDATE],

     DATEADD (WEEK, @WK, DATEADD (YEAR, @YR-1900, 0)) - 4 -
             DATEPART(DW, DATEADD (WEEK, @WK, DATEADD (YEAR, @YR-1900, 0)) - 4) + 7 AS [WEEK_ENDDATEDATE]
```

output

```
WEEK_STARTDATE            WEEK_ENDDATEDATE
2017-08-06 00:00:00.000   2017-08-12 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: this will give you `07-08-2017` and `13-08-2017`. Remove the `+1 from startingDate and change +7 to +6`

Comment: @mohamedfaiz No, did you test it?

Comment: @Sami yes I already test it. I already got the code from this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cf233caf-4ccd-4bca-add2-b5eb467f2dd4/convert-week-number-to-date-of-1st-day-of-that-week?forum=transactsql)

Comment: @mohamedfaiz no it will give you what u expect

Comment: @mohamedfaiz I think I also test it and gives the expected result , as Chanukya test it before poste the answer.

Comment: @Sami i got expected answer only

Comment: @Chanukya you please check it yourself. I am very sure. Starting date should be **06-08-2017** and ending date should be **12-08-2017**

Comment: @sami can you try in SQL Server Management Studio?. please hold on I will update.